# Abseil StrCat example results in std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, cmake, strcat, conan, abseil

I tried to use abseil's string library, but already the simple example does not run and fails with `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'`.

The snippet I use

```
#include "absl/strings/str_cat.h"
#include "fmt/core.h"

int main(){
    auto s1 = absl::StrCat("A string ", " another string", "yet another string");
    fmt::print( "{}\n", s1);
}
```

I use Abseil 20200923.2 with conan/cmake. I tried  gcc 10.1 and clang 11, both with the same result. How can I make this code run?

Comment: Please, open an issue to [Conan Center Index](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues), the support for official recipes is done from there.

Comment: I tried it without conan and cmake and found that it works with --std=c++14 but breaks with --std=c++17 or -std=gnu++2a.

Comment: Interesting, indeed standard cpp flags are not compatible, but incompatibilities errors are rare.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in godbolt, both under gcc and under clang...

https://godbolt.org/z/nasjrP

Therefore, I'd bet that this is a library issue: your main() code and Abseil and `fmt` and your standard library are not all on exactly the same c++ version.

Comment: If I compile Abseil from source with the c++-17 flag in the cmake file it works. However if I install Abseil through conan (even with -s cppstd=17 option) it seems to use a c++14 or c++11 version of Abseil and it breaks when compiling/linking in c++17 mode. With c++14 it also works with conan.